# Bug or limit of Delphi's max. constant integer values?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

```
const
  minDriveFreeSpace: Int64 = 1024*1024*1024*99;
```

and

```
var
  minDriveFreeSpace: Int64;
begin
  minDriveFreeSpace := 1024*1024*1024*99;
```

Will emit:

```
[dcc32 Error] DataStoreLocator.pas(92): E2099 Overflow in conversion or arithmetic operation
```

Is this a bug or limit of Delphi's max. constant integer values?

Comment: Interesting! It seems that it's also related to representing disk spce in that similar (duplicated) question pointed out by David.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to cast at least one value on the right side to `Int64`. For instance, both of these compile perfectly well on XE6:

```
const
  minDriveFreeSpace = Int64(1024) * 1024 * 1024 * 99;

var
  minDriveFreeSpace2: Int64;
begin
  minDriveFreeSpace2 := Int64(1024)*1024*1024*99;
```

Note that it can be any one of the rvalues that are cast. For instance, this works equally as well:

```
const
  minDriveFreeSpace = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * Int64(99);
```

This is documented in the [Delphi language guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Simple_Types#Integer_Types) (although rather poorly) - **emphasis** mine:

> In general, arithmetic operations on integers return a value of type Integer, which is equivalent to the 32-bit LongInt. **Operations return a value of type Int64 only when performed on one or more Int64 operands.** Therefore, the following code produces incorrect results:

```
var
I: Integer;
J: Int64;
... 
I := High(Integer);
J := I + 1;
```

> To get an Int64 return value in this situation, cast I as Int64:

```
...
J := Int64(I) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, My workaround (that didn't appear in the question) was a bit more verbose :P